# I cannot control SolutionColor in exam \shadedsolution

Tags: color, exam

I would like to choose solution color shading (green), and tried the following

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{exam}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[danish]{babel}
\usepackage{amsfonts,amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
\printanswers
\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{SolutionColor}{rgb}{0.0,1.0,0.}
\shadedsolutions
\pointpoints{point}{point} % Same form in plural and singular
\qformat {\textbf{Spørgsmål \thequestion}\quad(\thepoints):\hfill}
\renewcommand{\solutiontitle}{\noindent\textbf{Svar:}\par\noindent}
\begin{document}
  \begin{questions}
    \question[1]
      Hvad er meningen?
    \begin{solution}
      Ikke hvad vi gør, men hvordan vi gør det.
    \end{solution}
  \end{questions}
\end{document}
```

I get this result, while I hoped for **green** shading of the solution (Svar):
[image: MWE with grey shading]

How do I control the `SolutionColor` named color?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Thanks for providing a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/231/37357)—that made it a lot easier to answer your question and verify that the output is what you want!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at the definition of `\shadedsolutions` (from `exam.cls:6350`), you can see that it sets the color to gray:

```
\def\shadedsolutions{%
  \@ifundefined{definecolor}
  {%
    % output an error if the color package isn't used
    % (snipped)
  }%
  {%
    \definecolor{SolutionColor}{gray}{0.8} % this is overwriting your color
    \@shadedsolutionstrue
    \@framedsolutionsfalse
  }%
}
```

Therefore, you can get the result you want by putting `\definecolor` after `\shadedsolutions`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{exam}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[danish]{babel}
\usepackage{amsfonts,amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
\printanswers
\usepackage{color}
\shadedsolutions
\definecolor{SolutionColor}{rgb}{0.0,1.0,0.}
\pointpoints{point}{point} % Same form in plural and singular
\qformat {\textbf{Spørgsmål \thequestion}\quad(\thepoints):\hfill}
\renewcommand{\solutiontitle}{\noindent\textbf{Svar:}\par\noindent}
\begin{document}
  \begin{questions}
    \question[1]
      Hvad er meningen?
    \begin{solution}
      Ikke hvad vi gør, men hvordan vi gør det.
    \end{solution}
  \end{questions}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Fixed MWE output]

Comment: The sequence determines the outcome. Hence your solution solves my problem. Thank you.